# Analysis - Ratio Test Application

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

It is known that there exists a positive real number α such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}
((n^n)(α^n)√2πn)/n!= 1$,
where $n! = 1 × 2 · · · × n$. Find this α. (Hint: use the ratio test.)

I am aware of the ratio test in general and because $L = 1$ in this case, we can say that the series may be divergent or convergent using the ratio test. But how do I even begin finding alpha using the ratio test? Very confused and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stirling's approximation: $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n$, so $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{e}$. No ratio test needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1} \alpha^{n+1}\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}}{(n+1)!} \times \frac{n!}{n^n \alpha^n \sqrt{2\pi n}} = \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{1/2}\cdot\alpha\to e\alpha $$